# checkbox returning true or false in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, checkbox, boolean

I am trying to create a form that has an option, which if chosen, via a checkbox, returns true or false to the database. I have added the column to my db like so

```
rails g migration AddWantSellToPosts want_sell?:boolean
```

and also added the necessary params to the controllers page so that data is passed through. However no value is being returned to the database. I suspected it was my implementation of the check_box in Rails, however I am still not sure.

this is the html.erb

```
<%= f.text_field :price, :id => 'price' %>
<%= f.check_box :want_sell? %>
```

this is the posts_controller.rb

```
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

....

```
@post = Post.new params[:post].permit(:description, :picture, :tag_names, :price, :want_sell?)
@post.user = current_user
```

I should add i am new to rails and coding in general so I may be missing something really obvious!

Thanks

Comment: Rename the column to `want_sell`, `want_sell?` is a dynamic method that Rails will make available to check if the boolean is true/false. Also, are you saving the post? I see `@post = Post.new` but no `@post.save`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my comment...

Rename the column to `want_sell`, `want_sell?` is a dynamic method that Rails will make available to check if the boolean is true/false. Also be sure to call `@post.save`.